# Google Script for YouTube Analytics

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that runs some functions, and the main goal is to retrieve data from YouTube videos, including views, dislikes, likes, among other metrics, important to get so we can analyze correctly all data.

All metrics are correctly inserted by default in my Google sheet, except:

- AVERAGE_VIEW_DURATION_SECONDS
- SUBSCRIBERS_GAINED
- SHARES
- AUDIENCE_RETENTION_PERCENTAGE
- CARD_IMPRESSIONS
- CARD_CLICK_RATE

Is there any error in the script ?

```
// This is "Sheet1" by default. Keep it in sync after any renames.
var SHEET_NAME = 'Video Stats';

// This is the named range containing all video IDs.
var VIDEO_ID_RANGE_NAME = 'IDs';

// Update these values after adding/removing columns.
var Column = {
  VIEWS: 'D',
  LIKES: 'E',
  DISLIKES: 'F',
  COMMENTS: 'G',
  DURATION: 'H',
  AVERAGE_VIEW_DURATION_SECONDS: 'I',
  SUBSCRIBERS_GAINED: 'J',
  SHARES: 'K',
  AUDIENCE_RETENTION_PERCENTAGE: 'L',
  CARD_IMPRESSIONS: 'M',
  CARD_CLICK_RATE: 'N'
};

// Adds a "YouTube" context menu to manually update stats.
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var entries = [{name: "Update Stats", functionName: "updateStats"}];

  spreadsheet.addMenu("YouTube", entries);
};

function updateStats() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var videoIds = getVideoIds();
  var stats = getStats(videoIds.join(','));
  writeStats(stats);
}

// Gets all video IDs from the range and ignores empty values.
function getVideoIds() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRangeByName(VIDEO_ID_RANGE_NAME);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var videoIds = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][0];
    if (!value) {
      return videoIds;
    }
    videoIds.push(value);
  }
  return videoIds;
}

// Queries the YouTube API to get stats for all videos.
function getStats(videoIds) {
  return YouTube.Videos.list('contentDetails,statistics', {'id': videoIds}).items;
}

// Converts the API results to cells in the sheet.
function writeStats(stats) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var durationPattern = new RegExp(/PT((\d+)M)?(\d+)S/);
  for (var i = 0; i < stats.length; i++) {
    var cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.VIEWS + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.viewCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.LIKES + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.likeCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.DISLIKES + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.dislikeCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.COMMENTS + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.commentCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.DURATION + (2+i));
    var duration = stats[i].contentDetails.duration;
    var result = durationPattern.exec(duration);
    var min = result && result[2] || '00';
    var sec = result && result[3] || '00';
    cell.setValue('00:' + min + ':' + sec);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.AVERAGE_VIEW_DURATION_SECONDS + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.averageCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.SUBSCRIBERS_GAINED + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.subscriberCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.SHARES + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.shareCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.AUDIENCE_RETENTION_PERCENTAGE + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.audienceCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.CARD_IMPRESSIONS + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.impressionCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.CARD_CLICK_RATE + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.clickCount);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by correctly inserted? does the mentioned columns where empty? have you verified if the following columns really have a valid value when you retrieve your youtube stats via API? You could add `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(stats[i]))` inside your loop to verify its content

Comment: The columns that I mentioned above are empty when the script runs. How can I verify if they have a valid value via API?

Comment: Have you tried running the script?  Why are you asking us if there are errors?  Why can't you debug you own code and tell us what the problems are? I'd rather not debug your code for you if you not even willing to try yourself.  The point of the site is to help you learn not to do everything for you.

Comment: Of course I've tried running the script. As I said, I runned it, and the columns above-mentioned are empty. No bug is mentioned. And no, I'm not asking you to do it for me. If you're not willing to help, the best is that you skip my post then. Thanks anyway for sharing your thoughts with me.

Comment: You can add this `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(stats[i]))` inside your loop in `writeStats()`. Then check if for example `statistics.averageCount` in the json string has value for  `AVERAGE_VIEW_DURATION_SECONDS`

Comment: Sorry Ron, I'm quite new into Google App Script. When I add Logger.log inside my loop, then I get this error : "Attempted to execute onOpen, but could not save.".

Comment: When you add the Logger.log in the loop, you saved the changes then run `updateStats()` in your script editor. Then check the logs that will be shown. You know how to select which function to run in the script editor? (just click the dropdown menu beside the Debug button and select your desired function)

Comment: Yes, same here : "Attempted to execute ```updateStats()```, but could not save."

Comment: There might be a syntax error when you modified your script. (A red dialog box at the bottom left of your browser). Please provide a screenshot of the error or you can also check it on your side since it will show you the line number that has issues. [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3tpp.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239130/discussion-between-rui-fernandes-and-ron-m).

Comment: You'll excuse me, but I didn't manage to get it work correctly. Indeed, I do have an error saying ```formatdatestring``` isn't defined. Could you please help me?

Comment: You are using the day dimension which includes a date value formatted as string but in your code you did not define a `lastMonth` and `today` date variable in `getStats()`. See the [reference link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube-analytics#create_report) where you copied your code. I did try to change the dimension to video to get most of the metrics but I didn't got a channel id since my account doesn't have a youtube channel.

Comment: I have checked the code in the reference link, but I'm not able to understand where I should copy our YouTube channel id.

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed when checking the added logs, the reason why some columns were not filled-up is because it doesn't exist in the [Video Resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) which was obtained using [Videos.list method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

[image]

And regarding the missing fields, You need to use [Youtube Analytics API Reports Query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query) which is based on `channel id` and get the following [metrics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics): `averageViewDuration, subscribersGained, shares, relativeRetentionPerformance, cardImpressions, cardClickRate`

> Note: Some of the metrics listed are subject for deprecation